# Function with variable parameters as parameter to function C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am trying to create measuring class with one function that take function to be measured as parameter. Its called ChronoTimer.h content is:

```
#include <chrono>

template<typename TimeT = std::chrono::milliseconds, class ClockT = 
std::chrono::system_clock>

class ChronoTimer {
public:
    template<typename F, typename ...Args>

    static typename TimeT::rep duration(F func, Args&&... args)
    {
        auto start = ClockT::now();
        func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        return  std::chrono::duration_cast<TimeT>(ClockT::now() - start);
    }
};
```

Then I have "someClass" where is a function i want measure, and a function where I want to measure the function

```
#include "ChronoTimer.h"
long int someClass::measuredF( long end ) {
    long int cnt = 0;
    for ( long int i = 0; i < end; ++i ) {
        cnt = cnt + i;
    }
    return cnt;
}

void someClass::someFunction() {
    long int end = 10;
    auto duration = ChronoTimer<>::duration(someClass::*measuredF, end).count();
}
```

There is an error and i dont have enough understing/knowledge in C++ to get it working. Appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: start with replacing `someClass::*measuredF` by `&someClass::measuredF`

Comment: Hi Piotr, thanks for your reply. I changed the code as you suggest but i still get lots of errors like:

`error: member reference base type 'typename duration<long long, ratio<1, 1000> >::rep' (aka 'long long') is not a structure or union
    auto duration = ChronoTimer<>::duration( &someClass::measuredF, end).count();`

Comment: I assume that `measuredF` is not static...

Comment: no `measuredF` is not static

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass a callable object, `&someClass::measuredF` is not callable, its requires a `someClass` object.

You may do:

```
void someClass::someFunction() {
    long int end = 10;
    auto duration = ChronoTimer<>::duration([this](long int end) { this->measuredF(end); }, end).count();
}
```

or capture all:

```
void someClass::someFunction() {
    long int end = 10;
    auto duration = ChronoTimer<>::duration([=]() { this->measuredF(end); }).count();
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, this is not working, compiler returns error about expected semicolon after `this->measuredF(end)` and when I add it there is still error: `member reference base type 'typename duration<long long, ratio<1, 1000> >::rep' (aka 'long long') is not a structure or union
    auto duration = ChronoTimer<>::duration( [this](long int end) { this->measuredF(end) }, end).count();`

Comment: Hi Jarod, last error i described is related to assigning duration_cast to auto. So i finally got it working. Thx for help!